# Convert decimal under non-english Windows

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, invariantculture

I have installed C# application under Spanish MS Windows Server.

So this code is working in a wrong way.

```
decimal? top = 80.0m;
double convertedTop = (double)decimal.Parse(top.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**convertedTop is 80000 but it should be 80.0**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Don't do that.

Your code is extremely inefficient.

You should change it to

```
double convertedTop = Convert.ToDouble(top);
```

If the compile-time type of `top` is `decimal` or `decimal?` (as opposed to `object` or `IConvertible` or `ValueType`), you can use an even-more-efficient compile-time cast:

```
double convertedTop = (double)top;
```

---

To answer the question, `top.ToString()` is culture-sensitive.
You need to pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` there too.
`Nullable<T>` doesn't lift `ToString(IFormatProvider)`, so you'll need to do that on `Value` and handle `null` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! Could u explan difference between (double) and Convert.ToDouble() please?

Comment: @Peretz: `(double)` is a compile-time cast.  When used on an object, it can only perform an unboxing conversion.   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx.  `Convert.To*()` are complicated methods that essentially perform a `switch()` on the type of the argument and convert as appropriate.